# Do obsolete flags on comments require a moderator action or are they automatic?

Tags: discussion, comments, obsolete-information

When flagging a comment as obsolete, is it required that a moderator actually reviews the flag to take action on it, or after a certain number of similar flags is the comment automatically removed (like the way flagging "improve your accept rate" comments as off-topic magically made them disappear)? If it's automatic, how many flags does it take for the removal to go into effect?

Comment: All flags require moderator attention (unless you are hellbanned).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Comments can be automatically deleted if they get enough flags of the right type, even without moderator involvement. (As this post mentions, comments complaining about accept rate could be nuked with a single flag, but they're not the only ones.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks very interesting. Is there a list of comments that don't require attention by a moderator?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: All of them. See **Who can delete comments?** under the linked duplicate.

Comment: @animuson I was referring to comments that can be deleted by a single flag, without moderator attention.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: The only ones I know are "accept rate", "what have you tried", and common cuss words.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Technically only moderation attention flags (absolutely) need moderation attention. Off topic flags (the canned ones) can be handled (in a sense) by 10K+ users and never reach a diamond moderator. Also, they can be automatically dismissed in some cases, the more common of which is if there's a later close vote of the same type (the reasoning is: Hey, a higher rep user voted to close as off topic, so the off topic flag probably makes sense, let's not bother the mods with it, you know how angry they get when we bother them with silly flags).